# Struct Javolution Lib  Byteorder and Byte alignment 

Tags: java, struct, bytecode, javolution, real-time-java

How to set the byte or word alignment using javolution lib. This is like #pragma in CPP.

I am little bit confuse about the byte order. Please suggest me for the byte Order set in the same library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the Javadoc](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/io/Struct.html#byteOrder()), you need to add some code to your Struct to indicate what byte order will be used to read/write data:

```
public class MyStruct extends Struct {
    ... 
    public ByteOrder byteOrder() {
        return ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
    }
}
```